# How to store images locally with flutterflow

Tags: flutter, dart, flutterflow

I'm using flutterflow to create an app where the user can take a picture to be stored locally (and later displayed elsewhere within the app). However, the documentation only seems to offer solutions involving storing images online, when I want the entire app to be offline.

I've tried looking into app state, but it seems to only be for storing strings or small data, not media. Is there any way to store media locally and retreive it later with flutterflow?

Comment: There are plenty of examples of storing files to local storage using path_provider on SO.

Comment: I think there are no ways to save image in local using flutterflow. But you can create custom action and do some custom code can be able to save image locally.